# Trouble rendering hair in blender 2.77

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

When I try to render my mesh with hair particles in cycles, blender immediately crashes. But when I render the mesh without hair it renders in record time. 
I can't think of anything that might be wrong, considering the same mesh rendered perfectly ok in blender 2.76.
I am using an iMac Retina 5K, 27 inch, Late 2015 model. The processor is 3.3 GHz, intel core i5. Graphics is AMD Radeon R9, with a RAM of 32 GB.

Comment: You may have some informations about it following what is tell here in the documentation https://www.blender.org/manual/troubleshooting/crash.html

Comment: If Blender is crashing you should filçe a bug report and provide the Blend file that is causing the crash. It may also happen that you are hitting your hardware limitations or computer memory constraints, hard to know with so little info. What are your system specs? How are you rendering this? Please edit your question and provide more information. Could you upload your blendfile?

Comment: One of the changes for 2.77 is "Blender now requires OpenGL 2.1 minimum"